# SELECT em MYSQL resultando em apenas um registro

Tags: php, mysql

Faço um `SELECT` direto do painel do PHPMyAdmin:

```
SELECT `tx_type` FROM `tx_ar_tax` WHERE `tax_ref` = '75639' AND `tax_order` = 'O';
```

O phpMyAdmin retorna 7 registros, como está cadastrado e está correto

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas na saída do PHP só sai um valor na `ARRAY`:

```
<?php
$sql_tx = "SELECT `tx_type` FROM `tx_ar_tax` WHERE `tax_ref` = '75639' AND `tax_order` = 'O';";

$q_tx = mysqli_query($conn,$sql_tx);

$tx = mysqli_fetch_array($q_tx, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($tx);
echo "</pre>";

Array
[
    [tx_type] => 'ax-1069c'
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O *mysqli_fetch_array* vai te retornar apenas o array. Caso queira que mostre os demais você deve colocar em um while.

```
while($tx = mysqli_fetch_array($q_tx, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($tx);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

Comment: Obrigado X4vier pela ajuda, deu certo aqui ! abs